# How do I run Firefox browser with undetected_chromedriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a Firefox browser with undetected_chromedriver.
But only getting a default Firefox browser instead of getting the url I provided.
What did I miss or do wrong?

Here is the code I made so far.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver_path = "C:/Users/jay/Desktop/py/geckodriver.exe"
    Firefox_path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"

    option = uc.ChromeOptions()
    option.binary_location = Firefox_path
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)


    driver.get('https://google.com')

    time.sleep(10)
```

I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

`undetected_chromedriver` is ONLY for `chromedriver`.

It modifies values directly inside binary file `chromedrive.exe` and it doesn't know how to modify values inside file `geckodriver.exe`.

---

See also repo [GitHub - undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver).

There is:

- `"Works ... on .... Chromium based browsers"`.
- `"Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it."`

It means it automatically uses `chromedrive.exe` and it can't even use `geckodriver.exe`. And `chromedrive.exe` doesn't know how to communicate with `Firefox` - so it can't open page.

You can use it only with browsers which use engine `Chromium` - like `Brave` and maybe `Opera`, `Microsoft Edge` (but I didn't test it).